# How to register a new LLVM backend?

Tags: build-process, llvm, backend

I'm developing a very basic new LLVM backend for a RISC machine (named *Risco*), based on the existing Sparc backend and [this tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html). To register the backend, I've used the following.

- At RiscoTargetMachine.cpp:

  ```
  extern "C" void LLVMInitializeRiscoTarget()
  {
      // Register the target.
      RegisterTargetMachine<RiscoSimulatorTargetMachine> X(TheRiscoTarget);
      RegisterAsmInfo<RiscoMCAsmInfo> Y(TheRiscoTarget);
  }
  ```
- At Risco.td:

  ```
  def : Processor<"simulator", NoItineraries, [FeatureA]>;

  def Risco : Target {
          // Pull in Instruction Info:
          let InstructionSet = RiscoInstrInfo;
  }
  ```
- At TargetInfo/RiscoTargetInfo.cpp:

  ```
  Target llvm::TheRiscoTarget;

  extern "C" void LLVMInitializeRiscoTargetInfo() {
          RegisterTarget<> X(TheRiscoTarget, "risco", "Risco");
  }
  ```
- At the top level LLVM configure script:

  ```
  # Added Risco to the TARGETS_TO_BUILD variable at line 4965 (from svn trunk):
  all) TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86 Sparc PowerPC Alpha ARM Mips CellSPU PIC16 XCore MSP430 SystemZ Blackfin CBackend CppBackend MBlaze PTX Risco" ;;
  ```

After build, `llc -version` doesn't show the new target. Even `llc -march=risco test.ll` says it's an invalid target. What am I missing?

PS: Currently, I'm including the new target as a folder inside llvm/lib/Target. How can I change that so I can build the target separately, and load it dynamic with `llc -load`?

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience with LLVM has been that while the project's doxygen documentation is up to date, its tutorials are not. Even trying to walk through the compilation tutorial is frustrating.

Comment: It's not clear from your question so it could be a possibility that you're not running the new llc. Try which llc.

Answer (score 4):

The [default first template parameter](http://llvm.org/doxygen/TargetRegistry_8h_source.html#l00584) for `RegisterTarget` is `Triple::InvalidArch`. Try this:

```
extern "C" void LLVMInitializeRiscoTargetInfo() {
    RegisterTarget<Triple::UnknownArch> X(TheRiscoTarget, "risco", "Risco");
}
```

You might also need to register an assembly printer for your backend in RiscoAsmPrinter.cpp:

```
extern "C" void LLVMInitializeRiscoAsmPrinter() {
    RegisterAsmPrinter<RiscoAsmPrinter> X(TheRiscoTarget);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the last bit. My Makefile has `LOADABLE_MODULE=1` and builds the target as a shared object in the lib folder. In order to see the Risco target in the list of registered targets, I would run something like `./bin/llc -load ./lib/libLLVMRisco.so -version` assuming you are on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit at least 16 files in the root directory of LLVM:

1) In CMakeLists.txt add our target to: set(LLVM_ALL_TARGETS AArch64 ARM ... )

2) Add your target to Triple.h

3) Add HI/LO to llvm_root_dir/include/llvm/MC/MCExpr.h

...

16) ...

The complete steps can be found in LLVMCookbook. Page 228 to 238. Sorry I could not copy/paste  10 pages of tutorial here.

After editing all those 16 files, then build the LLVM using cmake: $cmake ~/llvm/src/ -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=YourTargetName and then $make

If you are lucky enough then your build will be successful, and you can see your target added to llc tools by issuing: $llc –version